# MdPaginatorIntl Internationalization example, Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Can someone help me with internationalization MdPaginator module? Angular Material Documentation says, "you need to provide your own instance of **MdPaginatorIntl**",  But I have no idea how to do this Thanks!

Documentation is [here](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview)

Answer (score 1):

In the next release, Angular Material will expose MdPaginatorIntl, but for now the only way to instantiate is to hack your way in to the Angular plumbing. [This link will show you how](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5573)

Comment: Thanks. I prefer to wait for the new release! :)